# Name or service error when retrieving posts from Product Hunt using API v1 and Python

Tags: python, rest, api, http, get

I am trying to retrieve a list of posts from Product Hunt. I have been able to create the request outlined here in the documentation: https://api.producthunt.com/v1/docs/oauth_client_only_authentication/oauth_test_use_the_client_level_token_for_read_api_access

In Postman it has worked just fine and I receive my object list. (I know the API is deprecated, but it isn't discontinued).

Now, I am trying to replicate the call in Python, with no luck. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? Here is my code... I have redacted my id, secret and token for safety.

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("api,producthunt,com")

payload = {
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Host': "api.producthunt.com",
    'Authorization': "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }

conn.request("GET", "v1,posts", payload, headers)

result = conn.getresponse()
data = result.read()

print(data)
```

and this is the error trace that I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", "v1,posts", payload, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 938, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: You are using "," instead of "." and "/", is that really what you want?

Comment: @AlexanderSantos, i'm not sure i understand what you are saying. Where?

Comment: At `HTTPConnection("api,producthunt,com")`and at `"v1,posts"`. I am not sure if this will help you in anyway, but [here is an example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples)